# What can you say about the traces and determinants of these two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A is the n × n matrix representing the projection onto the subspace V⊂R$^n$
, with dim(V) = m, and
B represents reflection across V.

There are some basic observations I can make, specifically about A and B separately. I think, however, that I am missing the important observations that this question is asking about. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

First note, that determinant and trace are invariant under base change, that is for every invertible $S$ we have 
$$ \det(SAS^{-1}) = \det A, \qquad \def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}\tr(SAS^{-1}) = \tr A $$
so we are free in choosing the right basis.

Now let $(v_1, \ldots, v_m)$ a basis of $V$, and $(v_{m+1}, \ldots, v_n)$ a basis of the complement of $V$ along which we are projecting/reflecting (the orthogonal complement for example, note that $A$ is not given uniquely by the description, there are many [non-orthogonal] projections onto $V$). Then we have 
$$ Av_i = \begin{cases} v_i & i \le m \\ 0 & i > m\end{cases},
\qquad Bv_i = \begin{cases} v_i & i \le m \\ -v_i & i > m\end{cases}
$$That gives 
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &\ldots\\
                       0 & 1 & \ldots\\
                       &     &\ddots \\
&&&1\\                       
&    &  &  & 0 &\\
                         &&&&&\ddots \\
                            &&&&&&0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad  B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &\ldots\\
                       0 & 1 & \ldots\\
                       &     &\ddots \\
&&&1\\                       
&    &  &  & -1 &\\
                         &&&&&\ddots \\
                            &&&&&&-1 \end{pmatrix} $$
Now we can read of determinant and trace.